# JavaScript - Compare two array and insert if not exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays. For example:

```
var array1 = ["Q3","Q4","Q5","Q6","Q7","Q8"];
var array2 = ["Q5","Q6","Q7"];
```

The output of second array should be,

```
[0,0,"Q5","Q6","Q7",0];
```

I want to compare the first array with the second and fill the missing values with Zero `0`.

`array1` is the primary array and, for now, `array2` will have this 3 values initially.

Comment: is array1 the primary array? or could array2 have more items?

Comment: you can use 2 l nested loop to solve this one. Array1 will be outer loop and array2 will be inner loop and check if array1 value is present in array2. If its  present then set a flag. After inner loop end check flag value and set the value in array1 accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example arrays a simple map -> includes would work:

```js
var array1 = ["Q3","Q4","Q5","Q6","Q7","Q8"]; 
var array2 = ["Q5","Q6","Q7"];

console.log(array1.map(i => array2.includes(i) ? i : 0))
```